# How to change the default keybinding of a mode?

Tags: key-bindings

I am using [skewer mode](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode) which binds `C-c C-z`  to `Select the REPL buffer`

This conflicts with another mode's (which I use simultaneously) keybindings.

What is the canonical way for me to make it so that `C-c C-z` is instead **`C-c C-r`** in Skewer mode?

Comment: `(define-key skewer-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-z") nil)` then `(define-key skewer-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-r") 'the-select-the-REPL-buffer-command)`

Comment: @Drew Please write your comment as an answer if you are sure that this is the canonical way.

Comment: @Tobias: I don't believe in canonical ways. ;-)